# Puppeteer error - Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, docker, puppeteer

### Error while running the following code:

here is all the code that I'm using to try download an PDF file that was created previously:

```
import puppeteer, { PDFOptions } from 'puppeteer';

interface Request {
  pageContent: string;
  pdfOptions?: PDFOptions;
}
class GeneratePDFFileService {
  async execute({ pageContent, pdfOptions }: Request): Promise<Buffer> {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch ({ 
      headless: true, 
      args:['--no-sandbox'] 
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent(pageContent);
    const pdfFileOptions = pdfOptions || {
      printBackground: true,
      format: 'a4',
      margin: {
        top: '2cm',
        left: '2cm',
        bottom: '2cm',
        right: '2cm',
      },
      preferCSSPageSize: true,
    };
    const pdf = await page.pdf(pdfFileOptions);
    await browser.close();
    return pdf;
  }
}
export { GeneratePDFFileService };
```

Here is the error:

```
application  | Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/chromium-browser ENOENT
application  | 
application  | 
application  | TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
application  | 
application  |     at onClose (/usr/app/node_modules/puppeteer/src/node/BrowserRunner.ts:261:9)
application  |     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/app/node_modules/puppeteer/src/node/BrowserRunner.ts:250:9)
application  |     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
application  |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:280:12)
application  |     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
application  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

Puppeteer version: 
`"puppeteer": "^13.1.3",`

I've tried some tips in [troubleshooting.md](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md), but have no idea if I'm doing it right.